# Qt font tracking

Tags: qt, fonts, tracking

Is there any way to set font tracking in Qt?

[image]

Comment: I wanna set font tracking for QLabel

Comment: I think he means the space between each character. "letter-spacing - defines the amount of space between each letter. This is usually called **tracking** in print design." [Source](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/aa112000c.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [void QFont::setLetterSpacing ( SpacingType type, qreal spacing )](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qfont.html#setLetterSpacing).

> Sets the letter spacing for the font to spacing and the type of
>   spacing to type.
>
> Letter spacing changes the default spacing between individual letters
>   in the font. The spacing between the letters can be made smaller as
>   well as larger.